# Quaternion, How to rotate object slowly?

Tags: unity-game-engine, rotation, quaternions

I use Unity 5.3.4 and Oculus VR and implement an application in VR envrionment.

I would like to rotate an object slowly using `Quaternion`. For example, when I turn my head 180 degrees to the right, the MainCamera turns around 90 degrees.

In Unity, tracked input of Oculus-VR is calculated automatically and return to `Quaternion` data.

```
void Update()
{
    transform.localRotation = UnityEngine.VR.InputTracking.GetLocalRotation(UnityEngine.VR.VRNode.CenterEye);;
}
```

So I will rotate camera using this `Quaternion`. But I don't know how to rotate slowly.

I tried to calculate arithmetic operation, e.g. multiplication, division, to `Quaternion`. But it's not working

How to calculate `Quaternion`?

Comment: in theory (my heads theory) you should be able to archieve that by lerping the quaternion between old rotation and the newly received one, with t = 0.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use:

```
transform.localRotation =Quaternion.Lerp( transform.localRotation, UnityEngine.VR.InputTracking.GetLocalRotation(UnityEngine.VR.VRNode.CenterEye), Time.deltaTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this
  `Quaternion euler = new Quaternion();
  euler.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0,HeadRotation,0);
  Camera.main.transform.Rotate(euler.eulerAngles);`

Comment: I think the point yes had was that it would be *even cleaner* if you just use the vector3 directly in `Camera.main.transform.rotate`. Also, "Head Rotation" as an expression isn't valid C#.

Comment: @SamWalls i also question that its efficient, theres calculations involved in both creating the quaternion from euler angles and getting them back.

Comment: so who gave it a thumbs down ?? I don't understand what is so unefficient about it .@yes where did you mention that you already have an euler angle .

Comment: @yes mind you that calculations are involved in writing all calculations in a single line also , what you said has no logic .

Comment: @LumbusterTick idk what this "all calculation in a single line" is supposed to mean. getting euler from quaternions or vice versa requires a whole bunch of calculations, read here  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conversion_between_quaternions_and_Euler_angles

Comment: @yes and a quaternion lerp wont ??? man people like you are whats wrong with this community , you cannot donvote an answer just because its not in a single line .

Comment: it has nothing to do with the code not being on a single line, its because you have 2 completely unneccessary, nonsensical, calculations in your code. I dont like the Lerp solution either, its a misuse of lerp. in the way its used in the above answer, if youd do the calculations by hand, you would never end up at the desired rotation (though youd get quite close).

Comment: @yes you asked how to calculate quaternion in your question!

Comment: its not my question. also you "get back" a quaternion from transform.rotate, so in a sense this also is "how to create a quaternion". as said in my OP, why not just only rotate, i would not take any offense at all, my only critics was that you create a quaternion for no other reason than to get euler angles back.

Comment: @yes did you mention that you already had a quaternion angle ?

Comment: if you refer to my answer to the OP, i thought the OP wanted to only receive half the input speed. if you lerp to a quaternion by 0.5, it means you only "use" half the rotation. also i removed my downvote to make you happy again, i didnt think it would hit you so hard, that wasnt my intention.